# What level of math does one usually require before being able to publish a paper of their own

Tags: publications, mathematics, journals

At what level does someone become skilled enough in math to publish their work? I am an undergrad student currently in calculus 2. My dream is to publish work of my own, but I know that will come to fruition quite a while down the road due to my current level of math. I would appreciate any advice you have to give. Thank you in advance. Just to clarify I am asking about math papers.

Comment: If you want to do math research, you can start at any point on your own, but much of research (esp at first) consists of learning what's been done before.  Go read and think and compute for yourself.  And try to prepare yourself for something like a summer research program, where you'll get important guidance.

Comment: There is no such criteria. No journal asks 'what math courses have you taken' when you submit a paper.  IMHO, you're putting the horse before the cart.  The goal shouldn't be 'to publish', that's like saying "I want to be famous." (Famous for what? For how long? In what way? Why?) In stead, the goal should be to find and address an unanswered question that interests you.

Comment: @mikemtnbikes I agree with your comment, but you have the cart horse analogy backwards. The horse before the cart (pulling rather than pushing) is the natural thing to do. The cart before the horse is backwards.

Comment: @EthanBolker Oops. How embarrassing...

Comment: @mikemtnbikes, thought provoking, anyway.

Comment: @EthanBolker I don’t know about you, but my horse always  goes behind the cart. I thought everybody sets up their cart that way. Guess not...

Comment: There's lots of papers in lots of fields that don't have math at all. Many of my colleagues do both qualitative and quantitative research. This is unanswerable without a field.

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- I'm very sorry for not clarifying better. The field I want to work in is mathematics. As other comments have shown, I should try to figure out what exactly I want to work with but until then I should keep studying a broad range of mathematics.

Comment: It's ok - just edit your post to clarify that you want to publish math research

Comment: @VN,  Most people who publish high quality scientific papers and researches on reputable platforms usually have Ph.D.  Their papers/researches are always professionally and rigorously reviewed by their peers.

Answer (score 8):

This is something that varies with every individual. The best advice is to first get a broad mathematical education and then focus on some area of interest. But along the way to that broad education, seek insight into *why* things work as they do, not just the computational skill that you normally get in something like Calc 2.

Some people are able to publish as undergraduates, but it is fairly rare. However, an undergraduate math degree should get you to the point that you have actual insight into one or two areas (mine were analysis and topology) sufficient to dig deeply.

Research is normally very narrow, focusing on some tiny aspect of some small subfield if mathematics (or physics, or ...). But before you go narrow, first go broad, so that you have some sense of the possibilities. And also, some sense of the interconnections between things.

Working with a professor on some project of mutual interest will give you both a sense of what it is like to explore the unknown and also lets you take advantage of their insights. And letting them know now of your goals can help you attain them.

Solve a lot of problems. Get a lot of feedback. Look for the why, not just the how. Notice things. Keep notebooks. Ask questions.

---

This is, I know, more than you asked for, but you seem eager to learn and I appreciate that. Also note that whatever "research" I did as an undergraduate was, though attempted vigorously, laughably naive. Oh well. It came, eventually. And it was "hella fun".

Answer (score 4):

Especially at your early point in life, I think your label of what you want probably is not what you really-really want, if the meaning and entailments of labels were clearer.

That is, surely a mathematician's idealistic goal is to "understand/discover cool things".

Not clear that fame and fortune follow...

Not clear what the prerequisites might be, for discoveries/understanding that is at the forefront of our *collective* understanding. I think it is important to distinguish goals/progress of *personal* understanding from progress in *collective* understanding. In many regards, all that any of us can do is advance our own understanding. If by chance it is also an advance in collective understanding, so be it. Maybe that makes it "publishable" in the sense of peer-reviewed journal stuff.

But/and, especially at an early point, trying to think in terms of novelty in collective understanding, rather than the honest and productive idea of one's own personal understanding, is corruptive and distracting.

So, in principle, there are no entrance requirements for "publishing a paper"... except that it be suitable for the journal you submitted it to. What the heck does that mean? Well, it is a professional thing which is not what one might imagine. You'd want advice. Style-of-writing is very important to get your foot in the door, and professional writing in mathematics is not at all like textbooks, even at graduate level.

But, again, I'd suggest not describing your goal as "publishing papers" or even "doing research" but something more like "trying to understand things..." This is a much less corrupting name for the thing.